# How can I migrate an existing IDEA Scala-based Android project to SBT?

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have an Android app written in Scala, which I've been building using IntelliJ IDEA 13 using the Scala plugin directly, with no other build system. Now the project has grown somewhat, with a second (library) module and some external libraries, I'd like to move to a proper build system with different configurations and dependency-management.

I've found lots of information about importing existing SBT projects into IDEA, and starting a fresh SBT Android project in IDEA from a template, but I've not found any information on setting up SBT for an existing IDEA project. All the documentation I've found assumes you're starting from scratch. What process should I follow to achieve this?

Comment: I'm yet to learn a bit more about Scala/sbt/Android development stack, but been hearing quite a few successful stories about [android-sdk-plugin](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin) you may like to try out.

Comment: In case you don't know this mailing list yet: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-on-android

Comment: Would you mind sharing the project structure so it's easier to get started?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I didn't do anything special in IntelliJ. I just created an Android project in the usual way, then added a Scala 2.10 facet to the main module, and set up the "compiler library" with the JARs from `/usr/local/share/scala/lib`.

Comment: I'm gonna reproduce your project, but before spending much time on it, let me ask you about sharing yours on GitHub. Possible? I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a traditional (non-Gradle) project layout for Android:

1. Back-up.
2. Create `project/plugins.sbt`with the following contents:

   `addSbtPlugin("com.hanhuy.sbt" % "android-sdk-plugin" % "1.3.0-SNAPSHOT")`
3. Create `build.sbt`. Here's a [sample](https://gist.github.com/jvliwanag/30c94dd7fdbc09230792) using support-v4 and gms. Edit accordingly.
4. Delete intellij artifacts (*.idea, *.iml, etc)
5. Open up intellij and import the project based on sbt. (Optional: Enable auto-import)
6. Open up project properties. Set the SDK to the proper Android SDK.
7. On your module, add the Android Facet. Make sure that the directories (src, gen, etc) point to the proper paths.
8. Connect your device
9. `sbt run`

Caveats:

- If you enable auto-import, intellij unmarks the 'gen' folder as a generated sources directory. You will have to mark this directory back as a directory for generated sources should this happen.

-- Update:

If you have a multi-project set-up, create a build.sbt (or project/Build.scala) on your top level project directory.

Examples from android-sdk-plugin:

- https://gist.github.com/pfn/5872770
- https://gist.github.com/pfn/5872679
- https://gist.github.com/pfn/5872427

Comment: There's one thing that's not quite clear yet. My project is in a `myproject` directory, with the main module in `myproject/myproject`, and `src/`, `res/` directories inside that. Where should I create these SBT files? In the project directory, the module directory, or somewhere else? And what about the library module?

Comment: For a multi-project set-up, you'd want to create a single build.sbt or (project/Build.scala) on your top level directory.